# Узнать возраст операция с датой в php

Tags: php, дата

Например есть сегодняшняя дата 26.10.2015 и есть дата рожденья пользователя 9.2.1998

Вопрос. Как от текущей даты отнять дату рождения человека и получить в результате его возраст.

Написал такой код а что дальше не знаю

```
$mydate = date("j.n.Y");
$user_date = "9.2.1998";
```

9 - Это день месяца а 2 - это месяц  В базе хранится без ведущих нулей.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDifference(DateTime $startDate)
{
    $currentDate = new DateTime();
    $Diff = $currentDate->diff($startDate);
    return $Diff->y;
}

var_dump(getDifference(new DateTime('21.11.1991')));
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Comment: Попробуйте тут: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: Может ошибка с версией PHP

Answer (score 0):

Вот и ответ нашел!

```
$date1 = '9.2.1998';  
$date2 = date("j.n.Y"); 
$time1 = strtotime($date1);  
$time2 = strtotime($date2); 
$v  = abs($time1-$time2); 
echo date('y',$v)-70;
```

Где $date2 текущая дата

а $date1 дата рождения пользователя

Comment: Что за странные магические числа...Не проще ли так: `$d1 = date('Y', strtotime('9.2.1998')); $d2 = date("Y"); echo $d2 - $d1;`

Comment: Можно и так, спасибо

Comment: Это у меня было указано в ответе) Если вас он устраивает, можете отметить правильный ответ галочкой. Чтобы не оставлять вопрос открытым.

Answer (score -1):

Самый короткий способ:

```
$user_date = "9.2.1998";
$d1 = date('Y', strtotime($user_date)); 
$d2 = date("Y"); 
echo $d2 - $d1;
```