# Как прибавить к возрасту несколько дней?

Tags: php

Как прибавить к возрасту несколько дней?
в этом вопросе я посмотрел как узнать возраст: [как узнать возраст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461323/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-php)
а как прибавить к возрасту несколько дней?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php

Comment: Этот способ не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опираясь на то, что вы смотрели `DateTime`, то можно, следуя традиции, идти дальше и смотреть:

[DateTime::modify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php) → Изменение временной метки

Объектно-ориентированный стиль

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Процедурный стиль

```
<?php
    $date = date_create('2006-12-12');
    date_modify($date, '+1 day');
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Результат выполнения данных примеров:

```
2006-12-13
```

Собственно, вместо `+1 day` могут быть разные числа, а также прибавлять/убавлять можно не только день, но и месяц, год и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
$neskolkoDnyamiPozhe = date("j.n.Y", strtotime($vozrast)+10*86400);//+10 дней к возрасту
```

если $vozrast, это дата в виде текста